# How can I integrate version control methodology with front end or non technical people?

Tags: version-control

The benefits of version control are obvious to someone who's producing text.  How can I convince other disciplines, such as graphics or documentation writers?  Or do i just version my stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working on the same product but in different areas you should use the same tool and put the different information like documentation into a centralized point e.g. Repository of a version control tool.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps different tools would help.

Does their stuff have to be with your code or could they use something like sharepoint which is more suited to storing documents.